# Merge and sort any two sorted arrays in R

Tags: r, mergesort

I think I have the logic for merging the two sorted vectors but do not know why this is taking a really long time to compute even with small vectors. As there is no error when I run this code, I am looking for pointers as to what the issue is. I want this function to work with large vectors and thus want it to be computationally efficient as well.

Here is the code I am working with: 
Code modified based on suggestions in discussion: Runs but does not work as expected.

```
a <- seq(2, 100, 10)
b <- seq(3, 100, 15)

mergeSort2vectors = function(a, b){
n1 <- length(a)
n2 <- length(b)

c <- rep(NA, n1+n2)

i = 1
k = 1
n3 <- min(n1, n2)

while(i <= n3){
    if (a[i] < b[i]){
        c[k] = a[i]
    } else{
        c[k] = b[i]
    }
    i = i+1
    k = k+1
}

if(n1 > n2){
    c[(n3+1): n1+n2] <- a[(n3+1): n1]
} else {
    c[(n3+1): n1+n2] <- b[(n3+1): n2]
}
c}



sorted <- mergeSort2vectors(a,b)
```

I want the sorted vector in this example to be 2, 3, 12, 18, 22, 32, 33, 42, ..., 93.

Comment: Do you need `l1 <- max(length(a), length(b));pmin(a, "length<-"(b, l1), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Would you please elaborate a little, why this would be needed? The vectors don't have any missing values and if one vector is of smaller length, then the loop must stop and just copy the values of the longer vector.

Comment: Here, I am making the lengths of the smaller vector same as that of large vector by assigning the `length<-`.  it will pad NA at the. end, which is then replaced with `pmin` on both vectors a, b.  if there is NA in one of the vector, `na.rm = TRUE` replace that with the corresponding 'a' value

Comment: i couldnt run your loop as it is taking some time

Comment: Yes, that is the problem and there is no error even with a small vector. Is the logic for the sorting correct? Is there a better way to write this loop?

Comment: does my code work for you

Comment: I added the return statement and it works, after adding your code.  Just that the answer is not correct. as get 2 followed by all zeroes.

Comment: i get `pmin(a, `length<-`(b, length(a)), na.rm = TRUE)#
 [1]  2 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92`

Comment: If what I understand is correct, the `pmin` should give the expected output and would be very fast compared to the loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208736/discussion-between-anusha-and-akrun).

Answer (score 0):

See the function `Merge` in Rfast2 . It does exactly what you're trying to do

https://rdrr.io/cran/Rfast2/man/Merge.html

https://cran.r-project.org/package=Rfast2